# Lua create function with upvalues C

Tags: c, lua

i'm trying to create a function that has 2 upvalues when inspected from lua.
debug.getinfo(fvalues).nups should be 2 .

```
static int fvalues (lua_State *L) {
    int n = lua_gettop(L);
    if (str.size() == 0) {
        str = "This_is_a_test";
    }
    const char *cstr = str.c_str();
    lua_pushstring(L, cstr);
    lua_pushcclosure(L, &fvalues, 1);
    lua_pushstring(L, cstr);
    lua_pushcclosure(L, &fvalues, 2);
    lua_pushstring(L, cstr);
    return 1; 
}
```

Shouldn't pushclosure create an upvalue in this case, i didn't understand well how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 5):

Is not very clear what you're trying to do. If you want to push C-closure `fvalues` with 2 upvalues, then:

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    lua_pushstring(L, "Hello, World!");
    lua_pushnumber(L, 3.14);
    lua_pushcclosure(L, fvalues, 2);
    lua_setglobal(L, "fvalues");
    ...
}

static int
fvalues(lua_State *L)
{
    printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)); // Hello, World!
    printf("%g\n", lua_tonumber(L, lua_upvalueindex(2)); // 3.14
    return 0;
}
```

Closure is created by passing `lua_CFunction` and values at top of the stack to `lua_pushcclosure`. Body of that function has nothing to do with creation of upvalues, it only can use them via `lua_upvalueindex(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is something like:

```
int fvalues (lua_State *L) {
    ... get function arguments with lua_to* functions ...
    ... get upvalues with lua_getupvalue and lua_upvalueindex and lua_to* functions ...
    ... use arguments and upvalues ...
}

int callFValues(lua_State *L) {
    const char* cstr = "This_is_a_test";
    // push two values that will be upvalues of fvalues
    lua_pushstring(L, cstr);
    lua_pushstring(L, cstr);
    // create closure using the two upvalues:
    lua_pushcclosure(L, &fvalues, 2);
    // call it: 
    lua_pcall(L, 0,0,0);
    return 1; 
}
```

Then register `callFValues`. If you want to return a closure (as is common in Lua script), for use by your Lua script, pretty much same:

```
int createClosure(lua_State *L) {
    const char* cstr = "This_is_a_test";
    // push two values that will be upvalues of fvalues
    lua_pushstring(L, cstr);
    lua_pushstring(L, cstr);
    // create closure using the two upvalues:
    lua_pushcclosure(L, &fvalues, 2);
    return 1; // return it to caller
}
```

Then register `createClosure`, call it from script as `fval = createClosure()` then `fval` is a closure of `fvalues` with the two upvalues created by `createClosure`.

Read [section 27.3.3 of PIL](http://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.3.html) for detailed example. But in your code, your fvalues, which is a lua_CFunction you want to close and call, is itself creating a closure of itself, this makes my head spin :)  Also,

```
lua_pushstring(L, cstr);
lua_pushcclosure(L, &fvalues, 1);
lua_pushstring(L, cstr);
lua_pushcclosure(L, &fvalues, 2);
```

creates a closure for fvalues with the first string added to stack being its one unique upvalue; this removes the string from stack, and puts closure on stack; then you push another string, and create another closure of fvalues, this time with 2 upvalues: the first upvalue is the first closure created, the second one is the second string added. My head spins even more. Hopefully with the PIL section and the pattern I show you have clearer picture.